# Using Handlebars with HAML

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, haml

I'm trying to use HAML with Handlebars and things are not working properly creating errors like:

```
Assertion failed: Expected hash or Mixin instance, got [object Function]
```

Below is my view:

```
%br

%h2 Replies

%table{:class => "table table-striped"}
  %thead
    %tr
      %th Id
      %th Description
      %th User
      %th Actions
  %tbody
    - @ticket.note.each do |note|
      %tr
        %td= note.id
        %td= note.description
        %td= note.user.name
        / %td= link_to 'Edit', edit_note_path(note), :class => "btn btn-small" 
        %td <script type="text/x-handlebars">{{#linkTo 'notes'}}Edit{{/linkTo}}</script>
= link_to 'New', new_note_path, :class => "btn btn-primary"
```

What I'm trying to do is use handlebars on an Edit link only and hook it up to Ember.js

What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: That code looks ok at first glance, does not sound like a haml/handlebars issue. Can you post the rest of your ember.js app?

Answer (score 1):

While the issue could be Ember related, write the `script` tag in HAML to be consistent:

```
%td
  %script{:type => "text/x-handlebars"}
    {{#linkTo 'notes'}}Edit{{/linkTo}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this error ins't related to the haml. This happens when you try to extend a class and some value isn't a javascritpt object or mixin. In your case is coming a function.

```
// some mistake set a function to this 
App.MyMixin = function() {}

// here will crash
App.SomeView = Ember.View.extend(App.MyMixin, {
  title: '...'
});
```